# Can I change the default music player app on my iPhone? If so, how?

Tags: iphone, spotify, music.app

I want to change the default music app on my iPhone from Music to Spotify. Is this possible?  My first guess is that I would have to jailbreak my phone. Is there anyway to do it without jailbreaking?

Comment: How is Music the default app - in IOS you choose the app then it plays its data so you can have spotify working as well as Music?

Comment: I think he means when he asks Siri to play his favorite songs, or play jazz music etc, it defaults to the Music app rather than Spotify.

Comment: It's now possible to change the default audio app in iOS 14.5.

Comment: To add to @Synetech's comment: from what I found out, it is indeed possible - but only through asking Siri to play music. When Siri asks you to choose the music app to fulfil that specific request, iOS seems to save your answer and treats it as a general preference, so Siri might not ask you again for some time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Uninstall the default music app in iOS 11.**
Restart. voila.

My headphone control now works with wynk music app.
control center also shows wynk music.

Comment: This works! Now my headphones will stop switching to iTunes / music app in between listening to google play and phone calls. Thank you!

Comment: What an idea! That app has literally no purpose anymore.

Comment: You Sir, are the master of the universe. You just solved the biggest problem I had with an iPhone :) Automatically switched to spotify after uninstallation.

Comment: doesnt work for me on ios 12... it just doesnt start anything if I do not have apple music.

Comment: Thank you!! This was bothering me for an embarrassingly long time and it was such a simple fix I can’t believe I hadn’t tried it.

Answer (score 11):

I would say there isn't really any default music player on the iPhone. You could say that Apple's Music-app is the one that opens when you press "Play" on the lock-screen or the "multitasking bar", but there's no real advantage in that.

To answer your question, **no**. You are pretty much unable to change any default things in the non-jailbroken version of iOS.

With that said, you can do some tweaks having jailbroken your device. If you would like to use Siri to play your Spotify music, there is a jailbreak app for that called [AssistantLove](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/02/24/assistantlove/).
Other than that, you could use the jailbreak app [SpotiPlay](http://modmyi.com/content/8978-spotiplay-makes-spotify-your-default-ios-music-player.html). It makes the Spotify-application the one used on the multitasking bar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this on a non-jailbroken iPhone. And even after jailbreaking, there is currently no tweak which lets you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found out how.

1. Go to Spotify, don't play a song yet
2. Plug in your headphones then play a song
3. Now you lock your phone while the song is playing and now when you press the power button or the unlock button you should see the Spotify logo at the bottom left corner of the screen.

At least that's how I did it for Apple Music and then back to Spotify.

Comment: I did this and it seemed to work (for Play Music in my case).

Answer (score 1):

With iOS11 it seems like my iPhone changes back to the 'Music' app after a couple of minutes not using anything else. I did not like this since I hopped in my car and the music app started playing.

It's absolutely not the best option but for me it works quite well:

**UNINSTALL the official music app**

I have done this a couple of days ago and so far I actually like that scenario way better. Although it's still not perfect... I'd rather have the option to choose the default player. But my guess is we won't see that happening any time soon...

I'm aware that this only works if you do not have a library from iTunes on your phone. But I guess many people who use spotify as their default player don't have a giant library and any need to have the music app installed.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the default music app and restarting works on iOS 12.

One extra step I had to take to enable playback from the control center with the app closed was to go to Privacy > Media & Apple Music and enable access for the app.

---

As an alternative I use Evermusic Pro and I highly recommend it. I have no affiliation with the app or developer, just found it with search and after trying a bunch of other apps I think this is the best one.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry for bumping old thread. iPhone users can now download "MusicTube" for listening YouTube music on lockscreen.